# User (IPrincipal) not available on ApiController's constructor using Web Api 2.1 and Owin

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-web-api2, katana, asp.net-identity-2

I am Using Web Api 2.1 with Asp.Net Identity 2. I am trying to get the authenticated User on my ApiController's constructor (I am using AutoFac to inject my dependencies), but the User shows as not authenticated when the constructor is called.

I am trying to get the User so I can generate Audit information for any DB write-operations.

A few things I'm doing that can help on the diagnosis:

I am using **only** `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens` as authentication with Asp.Net Identity 2. This means that I removed the `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions())` that comes enabled by default when you are creating a new Web Api 2.1 project with Asp.Net Identity 2.

Inside `WebApiConfig` I'm injecting my repository:

```
builder.RegisterType<ValueRepository>().As<IValueRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Here's my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private IValueRepository valueRepository;

    public ValuesController(IValueRepository repo)
    {
        valueRepository = repo;
        // I would need the User information here to pass it to my repository
        // something like this:
        valueRepository.SetUser(User);
    }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        // User is not avaliable here either...
    }
}
```

But if I inspect the User object on the constructor, this is what I get:
[image: User]

The authentication is working, if I don't pass my token, it will respond with `Unauthorized`. If I pass the token and I try to access the user from any of the methods, it is authenticated and populated correctly. It just doesn't show up on the constructor when it is called.

In my `WebApiConfig` I am using:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

     // ... other unrelated injections using AutoFac
 }
```

I noticed that if I remove this line: `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()` the User is populated on the constructor.

Is this expected? How can I get the authenticated user on the constructor?

**EDIT:**
As Rikard suggested I tried to get the user in the Initialize method, but it is still not available, giving me the same thing described in the image.

Comment: very similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826551/authorization-with-asp-net-identity-autofac-owin-integration/37839448?noredirect=1#comment63164827_37839448). Turns out to be ordering of middleware registration, though the answer is still a work in progress at this time.

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies indeed with `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()`.

[This article by Brock Allen](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/) nicely explains why that is. The method sets the principal intentionally to null so that default authentication like cookies do not work. Instead, the [Web API Authentication filter](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) then takes care of the authentication part.

Removing this configuration when you do not have cookie authentication could be an option.

A neat solution [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21880216/70182), is to scope the Web API parts of the application, so that you can separate out this configuration to a specific path only:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var configuration = WebApiConfiguration.HttpConfiguration;
    app.Map("/api", inner =>
    {
        inner.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        // ...
        inner.UseWebApi(configuration);
    });
}
```

Comment: I spent hours on why my ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims is empty. Then I removed config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication(). after reading this answer. Now I'm able to access the claims. 
You saved my life. Thanks!.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but I've had exactly the same problems, as you've described above. I've managed to solve it using custom OWIN middleware component.

Some info about my application structure:

- Using MVC WebApp and WebAPI in same project (probably not the best option, but I have no time to change it, since deadline is approaching ;))
- Using AutoFac as IoC container
- Implemented custom ICurrentContext to hold information about currently logged on user (with CookieAuth in MVC and Bearer Token Auth in WebAPI), which is injected where needed (controllers, BAL objects, etc.)
- Using EntityFramework 6 for Db access
- Converted ASP.NET Identity to use int keys rather than string (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)

So on to the code. This is my ICurrentContext interface:

```
public interface ICurrentContext
{
     User CurrentUser { get; set; } // User is my User class which holds some user properties
     int? CurrentUserId { get; }
}
```

and implementation of it:

```
public class DefaultCurrentContext : ICurrentContext
{
    public User CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public int? CurrentUserId { get { return User != null ? CurrentUser.Id : (int?)null; } }
}
```

I've also created an OWIN middleware component:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;

namespace MyWebApp.Web.AppCode.MiddlewareOwin
{
    public class WebApiAuthInfoMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public WebApiAuthInfoMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
            : base(next)
        {
        }

        public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            var userId = context.Request.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
            context.Environment[MyWebApp.Constants.Constant.WebApiCurrentUserId] = userId;
            return Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Some information about this component: MyWebApp.Constants.Constant.WebApiCurrentUserId is some string constant (you can use your own) that I've used to avoid typos since its used in more than one place. Basicly what this middleware does, is that it adds current UserId to the OWIN environment dictionary and then Invokes the next action in pipeline.

Then I've created Use* extension statement to include OMC (OWIN Middleware Component) into OWIN pipeline:

```
using System;
using Owin;

namespace MyWebApp.Web.AppCode.MiddlewareOwin
{
    public static class OwinAppBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IAppBuilder UseWebApiAuthInfo(this IAppBuilder @this)
        {
            if (@this == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
            }

            @this.Use(typeof(WebApiAuthInfoMiddleware));
            return @this;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this OMC, I've put the Use* statement right after Use* statement for  Bearer token inside my Startup.Auth.cs:

```
// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions); // This was here before

// Register AuthInfo to retrieve UserId before executing of Api controllers
app.UseWebApiAuthInfo(); // Use newly created OMC
```

Now the actual usage of this principle was inside AutoFac's Register method (called on some bootstrap code at the start of web application; in my case this was inside Startup class (Startup.cs), Configuration method) for my ICurrentContext implementation which is:

```
private static void RegisterCurrentContext(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // Register current context
    builder.Register(c =>
    {
        // Try to get User's Id first from Identity of HttpContext.Current
        var appUserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

        // If appUserId is still zero, try to get it from Owin.Enviroment where WebApiAuthInfo middleware components puts it.
        if (appUserId <= 0)
        {
            object appUserIdObj;
            var env = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment;
            if (env.TryGetValue(MyWebApp.Constants.Constant.WebApiCurrentUserId, out appUserIdObj))
            {
                appUserId = (int)appUserIdObj;
            }
        }

        // WORK: Read user from database based on appUserId and create appUser object.

        return new DefaultCurrentContext
        {
            CurrentUser = appUser,
        };
    }).As<ICurrentContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

This method is called where I build AutoFac's container (hence the input parameter of type ContainerBuilder).

This way I got single implementation of CurrentContext, no matter how user was authenticated (via MVC Web Application or Web API). Web API calls in my case were made from some desktop application, but database and most of codebase were the same for MVC App and Web API.

Don't know if its the right way to go, but it has worked for me. Although I am still a little concerned how would this behave thread-wise, since I don't know exactly how using HttpContext.Current inside API calls would behave. I've read somewhere that OWIN Dictionary is used per-request basis, so I think this is safe approach. And I also think that this isn't so neat code, but rather a little nasty hack to read UserId. ;) If there's anything wrong with using this approcah, I'd appreciate any comment regarding it. I've been strugling with this for two weeks now and this is the closest I got of getting UserId in one place (when resolving ICurrentContext from AutoFac through lambda).

NOTE: Wherever there is usage of GetUserId, it can be replaced with original GetUserId (which returns string) implementation. The reason I'm using GetUserId is because I've rewritten ASP.NET to some extent for using ints instead of strings for TKey. I've done this based on following article: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 3):

The User property of the controller is not populated until the Initialize method is called which happens after the constructor is invoked, hence thats why the Identity is not yet populated with the authorzied user data.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rikard. I actually tried this and I still cannot access the User data in the Initialize method. (I'm editing the original question with that additional information).

Comment: Okay, maybe this http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that removing **config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()** allowed me to get the Identity in the constructor much earlier. However, I wouldnt suggest doing this if you are using Token Authentication.

Comment: Exactly. After more research I think what I'm trying to do makes more sense using Filters.

Answer (score 1):

**Thread.CurrentPrincipical** is available throughout the pipeline, you could skip the User registration below:

```
valueRepository.SetUser(User);
```

and access

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipical
```

In the repository instead, making the repository context aware. Furthermore, you could add a context layer.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of the above solutions work try this one:

```
    public ActionResult GetFiles()
    {
        ...
        string domainID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
        ...
    }
```