# Return 401 message from web api in forms authentication app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I am trying to return a 401 from my Web Api if the user is not logged in instead of sending them to the log in page when using the Authorize attribute on api methods.
I have seen several ideas on how to fix this but none have worked for me.

I am using web api 5.2.3 and it doesnt look like       response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
works anymore.

I have also tried to override HandleUnauthorizedRequest with no luck,
it still redirects me to the log in page.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I finally made it work by trying the answer here again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880817/make-web-api-authentication-return-401-instead-of-redirect-to-login-page

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I work with ASP.Net core, and the framework uses the same controller type for both Web APi and MVC. 
however, this is how I would attend to that issue, in the services.AddIdentity Method of my startup class

```
config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
    {
        if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
        {
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
        else
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri); 
        }
            return Task.FromResult(0); 
   } 
};
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Yea, im not using asp.net core. This is an MVC5 application. Thanks for your help though!