# AuthorizeAttribute for Web API (ASP.NET Core 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to use `AuthorizeAttribute` for my Web API methods.
But when user is not authorized method returns Login-View instead simple 401-status-code.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    // Another code.
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(opt => {})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
    // Another code.
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Another code.
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
    // Another code.
}
```

SimpleController.cs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public int Index(int Id)
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC 5 we have both `AuthorizeAttribute`:

1. `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` - which is used for the web API.
2. `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` - which is used for controllers with views.

But ASP.NET Core 2.0 has only one kind of attribute - for controllers with views.
What do I need to do to get status-codes (401, 403) instead views?

Comment: Are you using forms authentication?  Forms authentication will turn a 401 into a redirect to the login page.

Comment: @Amy Yes, I use forms authentication

Comment: That's your issue then.  Don't use forms authentication with web api.  Switch to cookie auth.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880817/make-web-api-authentication-return-401-instead-of-redirect-to-login-page

Comment: Is your whole project is api? Do you need to return 401/403 all over the project, right?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I use ASP.NET + SPA (React) and therefore I need to return 401/403 all over the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core Identity uses cookie authentication and therefore you can override `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Events` to make it work as you need. Identity provides `ConfigureApplicationCookie` configuration method for this.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    //this event is called when user is unauthorized and is redirected to login page
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```