# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute returning 200 (OK) on failure

Tags: security, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

I have some code similar to this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize("MyCustomPolicy")]
public string TestCall()
{
    var lanId = User.GetSomeClaimOnTheUserObject() ?? "Not Found";
    return "Hello From a TestCall Get Operation.  Claim is " + lanId;
}
```

The Authorize Policy looks like this:

```
var myCustomPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("SomeScheme")
    .Build();
options.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy", myCustomPolicy);
```

When I call it, it allows the call through if the AuthenticationScheme has been met, and blocks it if it has not (as expected).

The part that is not working is when it blocks the call, I would expect a 403 or maybe a 401 to be returned, but instead I am getting a 200 (OK) being returned.

**How can I get it to return a 401 when it fails the `Authorize` attribute?**

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue and after some search in SO I found basically this AuthorizeAttribute will return the view with login page when auth fails, instead of giving 401. To solve this you might want to try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190404/authorizeattribute-for-web-api-asp-net-core-2/55191263#55191263) or based on your use case search for some other examples, but essentially the cause of the problem is the same.